# Get metrics from Facebook Ads API

Tags: facebook, ads, facebook-ads-api

I am not able get the below metrics from Facebook API.
How can I calculate the these metrics, which appear in Facebook's own ads interface, from the Facebook Ads API:

- Reach
- Social reach
- Frequency,
- CPC,
- CPM.

Comment: All of these is available via the `/reportstats` endpoint. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adreportstats/v2.2

Answer (score 10):

When you have the Ad group ID, you have to issue an API call:
`https://graph.facebook.com/<AD-GROUP_ID>/stats`

Then you get answer like this:

```
{
  "id": "<AD-GROUP_ID>/stats/0/.....", 
  "impressions": 31, 
  "clicks": 0, 
  "spent": 0, 
  "social_impressions": 0, 
  "social_clicks": 0, 
  "social_spent": 0, 
  "unique_impressions": 0, 
  "social_unique_impressions": 0, 
  "unique_clicks": 0, 
  "social_unique_clicks": 0, 
  "actions": 0, 
  "connections": 0, 
  "adgroup_id": 6003713142141, 
  "start_time": null, 
  "end_time": "2011-11-07T06:43:21+0000"
}
```

To calculate the fields in the Facebook frontend:

'Reach' =  unique_impressions
'Social Reach' = is called social_unique_impressions.
'Frequency' = impressions / unique_impressions
'CPC' = spent / clicks
'CPM' = (spent * 1000) / impressions