# Getting Reach,Social Reach and Frequency metrics from Facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get metrics from Facebook Ads API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429557/get-metrics-from-facebook-ads-api)

I am unable to get the bellow metrics for the Ads,
     Reach,
     Social_Reach,
     Frequency,
     CPC,
     and CPM.

Please help me how to find out these metrics.

Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Some of these columns are the same data but named differently between the Facebook CSV ad reports and the Graph Ads API, while the other columns are calculated from the existing columns.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adstatistics/

```
Reach is called unique_impressions in the ad_statistics object.
Social_Reach is called social_unique_impressions.
Frequency = impressions / reach
CPC = spent / clicks
CPM = spent*1000 / impressions
```